# How to protect this uploading php from LFI

Tags: php, deface

```
<?php

    if($_POST){

        $imagentipo=$_FILES['imagen']['type'];
        $check=array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/png");

        if(in_array($imagentipo,$check)){
            $imagen=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
            $temp=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($temp,$imagen);
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action=test.php method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <img src="<?php echo $imagen ?>" width=50 height=50><br>
        <input type=file name=imagen accept="image/*"><br>
        <input type=submit name=lol>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code only allows .jpg .gif .png files to be uploaded; however, that can be bypassed with tamper data. Any ways to prevent this?

Comment: Do you want to try to detect invalid uploads, sanitize all uploads, or a combination of both? (Sanitizing is often easier/quicker than detecting.)

Comment: In order to be vulnerable to LFI (Local File Inclusion), you'd need to be including a file in your script (as the name alludes to).

Comment: @nickb: that's not correct. If you are able to read e.g. /etc/passwd it is still a file inclusion even if it is not executed.

Comment: @Chris - And where do you see, anywhere in this script, a local file that was specified by the user being read?

Answer (score 1):

Move uploaded files outside the web root and use functions from an image manipulation library to check if the uploaded file is indeed an image. Like Imagick:

```
try{
  $image = new Imagick($filePath);
}catch(Exception $e){
  // fail
}
```

If you don't have Imagick:

```
if(getimagesize($filePath) === false){
  // fail...
}
```